# magento error: "Can not add the item to your cart"

Tags: magento-1.4, cart

After a database restore I’m testing my e-commerce when I add the item to cart it always displays this error:

Can not add the item to your cart.

How can I do to resolve this problem?

I am using magento 1.4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You Should check log files to see possible errors of this problem